# Python - Regular expression to extract data from a variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the name stored in the variable below. I am trying to extract using regular expression but I am getting a invalid syntax error.

```
import re
var = 'Thomas/Male/'
output = re.search('([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)', var)
if output:
    print output.group(1)
```

Expected output 1 : Thomas
Expected output 2 : Male

Could anyone help on this. Thanks

Comment: You confused what is what in the code. http://rextester.com/RFUU47934

Comment: That's Python 2 code. You can't do `print output.group(1)` in Python 3. Also, you refer to a variable `match` without creating it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for alphanumeric characters:

```
import re
var = 'Thomas/Male/'
name, gender = re.findall('\w+', var)
```

Output:

```
'Thomas'
'Male'
```

Answer (score 3):

Check variables, and in python3 `print()` not `print`

```
import re
var = 'Thomas/Male/'
output = re.search('([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)', var)
if output:
    print(output.group(0))
    print(output.group(1))
    print(output.group(2))
```

Output:

```
Thomas/Male
Thomas
Male
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split`

```
var = 'Thomas/Male/'
var = var.split("/")
print(var[0], " = " ,var[1])
```

**Output:**

```
Thomas = Male
```

Answer (score 2):

If the data is always in the form you posted (`something/somethingElse/`) you could probably accomplish this easier by using `split()` rather than regex:

```
var = 'Thomas/Male/'
var_split = var.split('/')
print(var_split[0])
print(var_split[1])
```

Output:

```
Thomas
Male
```